# Not able to navigate to home screen after successful login in react native. Getting Error saying that you are trying to navigate to a nested navigator

Tags: react-native, authentication, navigation

After successful login, I am trying to navigate the user to the home screen and at the same time make sure that user does not get the login screen again if he/she is already signed in.

Below is how my screens are defined in App.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
       <NavigationContainer>
         <StatusBar backgroundColor={COLORS.white} barStyle="dark-content" />
         <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
           {isLoggedIn ? (
           <>
               <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BottomNavigator} />
               <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
             </>
           ) : (
             <>
               <Stack.Screen name="BoardScreen" component={OnBoardScreen} />
               <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
             </>
           )}
         </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
     </Provider>
```

And in Login component, I am trying to navigate to the home screen like this:

```
const handleLogin=async ()=> {
//On successful login, I am trying to navigate to the home screen
navigation.navigate("Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not manually navigate to conditionally rendered screens. Set `isLoggedIn` to true and navigation happens automatically.

See [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) for details.